# How to use absolute URLs while saving image sources in Database from CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR for creating newsletters. Everything went fine but when I send newsletters to email, the images stored there aren't displayed. The problem was caused by CKEDITOR using relative path for image sources, e.g. `<img src='/newsletter_images/news1/img1.jpg'>`.

I want CKEDITOR to use absolute urls such as:

```
<img src='http://www.mydomain.com/newsletter_images/news1/img1.jpg' />
```

The initialization I tried is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#editor1').ckeditor({ baseHref: "http://www.google.com/" });
    });
</script>
```

but didn't work.

On some posts I found using `baseUrl` and `baseDir` could solve the issue. I tried this:

```
 $('#editor1').ckeditor({
                   baseHref: "http://www.mydomain.com/",
                   baseUrl: "http://www.mydomain.com/newsletter/",
                   baseDir: "/newsletter/"
 });
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with the idea that the ckeditor is mainly for webpage-based use.  When you are sending all this in an email, I would think the ckeditor no longer keeps track of that *baseHref* for you.

If you found a way to add on that *baseHref* to each link before the email is sent out (using whatever server-side language you might be using,) it might end up with the result that you want.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
// get ckeditor text
// find/replace <a href=""></a> links with baseHref + link
// mail result
```

Comment: Thank you summea, for the time being i solved my problem according to your pseudocode using php str_replace function

Comment: Sorry, I should have recommended the str_replace function in the pseudocode.  Glad it is working out for now...!

Comment: @Prajwal can you show your code how do you get the data of ckeditor and modify it with str_repalce...

Answer (score 0):

As per the ckeditor documentation this is how it is set:

> {String} CKEDITOR.config.baseHref Since: 3.0 The base href
>   URL used to resolve relative and absolute URLs in the editor content.
>   config.baseHref = 'http://www.example.com/path/'; Default Value: ''
>   (empty string)

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html

Comment: When I'm using CKEditor 4, this does not affect images inserted via CKFinder. Not sure how it applies to other use cases, but this is a heads-up.

Comment: I believe the `baseHref` setting puts a `<base>` tag within the web content generated by CKEditor. Not good IMO. Search for `baseHref` in this file: http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/plugin93.html#CKEDITOR-config-cfg-baseHref

Answer (score 0):

baseUrl is the setting that you're searching for, but it's a CKFinder setting that you must set in your server. It can't be set on javascript, and of course not on a CKEditor instance.